# What does element#Identifier CSS selector do?

Tags: html, css

I wrote (or more likely copy\pasted) some code awhile ago, and looking at it now.. I don't exactly know what this CSS Selector does:

```
div#pop-up
```

My guess is that it's saying "if you're a div named pop-up, I'll select you", but I don't know for sure.  Can anyone confirm if this is a valid CSS selector, and if so what it's doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It selects the `div` element with an `id` attribute equal to "pop-up".

```css
div#pop-up {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">Hello, world!</div>
<div id="not-pop-up">Hello, world!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly, so this is a more specific way of identifying this element?  Say, to be sure I don't also have a span id'd pop-up?

Comment: @ewitkows specifying `div` here does narrow it down. The HTML `id` attribute must be unique on a HTML document, but you may have two different pages with two different elements with an `id` of "pop-up", and this would select the one whose type is `div`. This also increases the [*specificity*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), meaning style properties defined in `div#pop-up` would override those defined in `div` or `#pop-up` by themselves.

Comment: Got it, thanks @JamesDonnelly! (and everyone else, JD just beat y'all to the punch)

Answer (score 1):

It selects a div with the ID of popup. The `div` part is unnecessary, however in terms of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), it can change the weight of the rule.

Comment: ...or if you re-use that `id` across multiple documents. In one document you may have a `span` element with an `id` of "pop-up", for instance - and both may share the same stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

a `#` is the identifier for an `id` so this CSS says a `div` tag with an `id` of `pop-up`

Answer (score 0):

It's basically looking for a div with the id of pop-up.

An example would be:

```css
div#pop-up {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">DIV WITH THE CLASS "pop-up"</div>

<div id="pop-up">DIV WITH THE ID "pop-up"</div>

<span id="pop-up">SPAN WITH THE CLASS "pop-up"</span>
```